# ThreeJS model loader failed to load when used inside a class method

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to build a ThreeJS scene and have been coding it as a class:

```
export class RenderCanvas {

    #scene; // THREE.Scene()

    // Other properties and methods

    loadGeometries() {
        /* #scene is initialized prior to loadGeometries being called */ 

        var modelLoader = new FBXLoader();
        for (let path of listOfObjects) {
            modelLoader.load(path,
                function (obj) {
                    obj.traverse(function (child) { /* did nothing */ });
                    this.#scene.add(obj); 
                },
                function (xhr) {
                    console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + "% loaded")
                },
                function (err) {
                    console.error("Error loading the object")
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

In another JS file, a `RenderCanvas` class is instantiated and has the `loadGeometries()` method called.

The console showed that the model is loaded to 100%, but then the `Error loading the object` is triggered.

I noticed that if I use the procedural way instead of OOP and have `scene` as a global variable, then the model loader would work. So I am assuming that it has something to do with `this.#scene.add(obj);` missing the context, but have no idea if this is indeed the case or how to fix that.

What went wrong and how may I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `this` does not point to the right reference since you are inside the `onLoad()` callback. Try to save the `this` reference in a `scope` variable. Something like:

```
loadGeometries() {
    /* #scene is initialized prior to loadGeometries being called */ 

    var modelLoader = new FBXLoader();
    var scope = this;
    for (let path of listOfObjects) {
        modelLoader.load(path,
            function (obj) {
                obj.traverse(function (child) { /* did nothing */ });
                scope.#scene.add(obj); 
            },
            function (xhr) {
                console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + "% loaded")
            },
            function (err) {
                console.error("Error loading the object")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Alternatively, use an arrow function instead of normal one since the former one retains the `this` reference.

Comment: Coming from other languages, I did not think of literally storing the reference in a variable without explicit pointers... Javascript is interesting. This worked, thank you:D